# admin for editing particular user

Tags: python, django

I have users signed up to my site. I want to be able to edit their "bids". Basicaly, I want to be able to go to admin/user/user-bid/73 where 73 is a particular user's id and be able to edit their bid info. How can I do that?

I have the following in admin.py:

```
class UserBidAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        return self.model.objects.filter(user = request.user)

create_modeladmin(UserBidAdmin, name='user-bid', model=Bid)



def create_modeladmin(modeladmin, model, name = None):
    class  Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = model._meta.app_label

    attrs = {'__module__': '', 'Meta': Meta}

    newmodel = type(name, (model,), attrs)

    admin.site.register(newmodel, modeladmin)
    return modeladmin
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
class BidInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Bid


class UserWithProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ..........

    inlines = [BidInline]


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserWithProfileAdmin)
```

Comment: how do you access the bidinline? by url?

Comment: No, you don't have to access it by url. I put the Bid inside the User information. Let say, go to admin and you will see "Users", click that. Inside of that is the list of the users register in your site. Click any user on the list, you will see below the bid information

Comment: this allows me to changes user's bids. How do I display the bids and not change them? Thanks.

Comment: use readonly in admin, like this: readonly_fields = ('field_name', 'field_name', 'field_name')